# I can't get any unicode to work for degrees celsius.

Tags: css, unicode

I'm trying to get the degrees celsius symbol to show up using the pseudo selector :after but can't seem to any unicode to work. Using the symbol I have in place now prints a capital A before the degree symbol.

```
.temp:after{
content:"°C";
}
```

Comment: It seems to be working fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/E56Ag/  What type of encoding are you using for the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this:   `content:'\00b0 C';`  seems to work for me ? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/kvyFh

this could be helpfull to you : http://unicode-table.com/en/#00B0 *(it gives you html entities code too `&#176;` )*

Comment: This circumvents the problem (character encoding mismatch) instead of fixing it, and it makes the CSS source much less readable.

Answer (score 1):

I’m pretty sure it actually prints “Â°”, i.e. capital A with circumflex before the degree sign. The reason is that the file containing the CSS code is UTF-8 encoded but being interpreted as windows-1252 encoded. (The [degree sign](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/b0/index.htm), U+00B0, is 0xC2 0xB0 in UTF-8 encoding; if this is interpreted as windows-1252, or as ISO-8859-1, you get U+00C2 U+00B0, that is Â°.)

The solution is to declare the encoding of the file as UTF-8. The details depend on whether the CSS code is inside an HTML document or in a CSS file, and it may also depend on the server software. See the W3C page [Character encodings](http://www.w3.org/International/O-charset).

If the code is in an CSS file, the simplest fix is to save that file, in your editor, as UTF-8 *with BOM*. Depending on software, this might be simply flagged as “UTF-8” (as opposite to “UTF-8 without BOM”). Another way is to write the following at the very start of the CSS file:

```
@charset "UTF-8";
```